# Issue with controller validators generated with OpenApi Generator

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, swagger, openapi

So I have used OpenApi Generator to generate java classes (controller interfaces and response class). But because I set flag `user-optional` to `true`, every parameter which is not required in request is wrapped as `Optional`, but if I add constrains to min and max value my parameters looks like following: `@Min(1) @Max(10) Optional<Long> value`, and obviously my java app is not happy because there is no such validator which will validate `Optional`.

My snippet of generator file looks like that:

```
/test:
  get:
    tags:
      - test
    summary: Make it work already
    parameters:
      - name: id
        in: query
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: range
        in: query
        required: false
        schema:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          minimum: 1
          maximum: 10
          .
          .
          . etc
```

And second parameter looks like that `@Min(1) @Max(10) @RequestParam(value="range", required = false) Optional<Long> value`

Is there way to tell OpenApi to put validators inside of `Optional`?

Answer (score 0):

Update openapi generator plugin to 5.2.0 or above. This pull request added a fix https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/8708

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).